# How to add tests from test result to test list in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

For example, I have 1000 tests. I run them and 200 fail. I want to create a test list for the 200 failed list. What is the fastest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

1. Open the Test Results window.
2. Select "Result" in the filter column dropdown list (the one next to the one named Group By) then type "Failed" in the textbox next to it (if it's hidden click on the little arrow next to it).
3. Click on the green little button to Apply the filter. Now you should see only the Failed tests.
4. Select all of them then choose "Export Selected Test Results" and save the trx file.
5. Run the following command (or similar, if you don't have grep) to get a list with the test links:

   grep "TestLink id" failed.trx > out.txt
6. Create a new test list named "Failures", but don't add any test to it.
7. Open the .vsmdi file (should be next to your sln) and search for the Failures test list, then insert a  tag as a child node of this  and copy-paste all the  tags from the out.txt file above.

Please note that I didn't actually check if it works.

Cheers,
Paul